# Incrementally backup FTP to local computer

Tags: backup, ftp

I want to backup a FTP directory (not backup *to*) with a cron script running daily. I'd prefer a solution that could sync the FTP to my local computer; only copy files changed and remove files that have been deleted.

Is there such an application?

Comment: You could do something like [curlftpfs](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) and rsync. Also look at this: http://serverfault.com/questions/24622/how-to-use-rsync-over-ftp

Comment: @Patrick curlftpfs looks very nice, think this will be perfect together with rsnapshot that I'm already using

Comment: cool :-). Submitted as an answer so the question can be marked as solved.

Comment: There are several ftp mirroring programs, these will probably work best. That's also the term you should search for to find them...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [curlftpfs](http://curlftpfs.sourceforge.net/) and rsync to accomplish what you want.

curlftpfs is a FUSE filesystem that will let you mount a remote ftp location as a normal filesystem. Once it's mounted, you can use `rsync` to sync the mount with a local copy.

Comment: Actually ended up using lftp with mirroring from your link

Answer (score 0):

rsync can do that.

Make a script and put it in cron.

Comment: No it cant. Rsync doesnt work with ftp

Answer (score 0):

lftp is great (I wrote this post then found from your comment that you discovered it).  Make a bookmark to your site (from within lftp), then use a cron one-liner ... this one also commits each day's backups to git, so I can go back to an old backup if I have to.

```
11 01 * * * cd /home/my/backups; lftp bookmarkName -e "mirror --verbose -X *cache*;quit" && git add . && git commit -m "scheduled backup"
```

-X ignores files with cache in the name.